# Inequality involving $H^s$ and $L^2$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have this inequality which I don't see how to prove it.

We have $F \in C^s$, and $u\in H^s$.

I want to show that:

$$\| F\circ u \|_{H^s} \leq C(\| F \circ u \|_{L^2}+\sum_{r=1}^s \sum_{j=1}^r \sum_{|a_1|+\ldots + |a_j| =r } \| F^{(j)}(u) \|_{L^{\infty}}\| D^{a_1}u \ldots D^{a_j}u \|_{L^2})$$

I tried through estimating the equivalent norm, i.e $\| F(u) \|_{H^s} = \| (1+|y|^s)\hat{F}(u) \|_{L^2}$, but didn't get me far, also tried the definition of $H^s$ norm, but didn't get me far.

Any hints or advice are welcomed.
Edit: I added the constant C.

Comment: So your $s$ is just any real number? Then how do you define $C^s$?

Comment: Well, $s>n/2$ where $n$ comes from the space $\mathbb{R}^n$, I forgot to mention that it's $H^s(R^n),L^2(R^n),L^{\infty}(R^n),C^s(R^n)$.

Comment: @wisher, $s$ is an integer.

Comment: Then this is just the Chain rule, no?

Comment: Yes, apparently this is solved by Faa di Bruno's formula.